# Why use GLSL along with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

While trying to get the gist of **OpenGL**, I eventually ran into **GLSL**. I have used OpenGL before for miminal things, like triangles and colors (*since I haven't learnt much yet*), but when I found out about deprecated functions like *glBegin* and *glEnd*, I had to unlearn the things I had just learnt.

Now, I have come across *vertex buffers*, *vertex buffer objects*, *vertex and fragments shaders*... One thing I never understood though is why should one use GLSL? Why use GLSL along with OpenGL? What are the things you can't do using pure OpenGL? To me integrating GLSL shaders into programs adds complexity, since you have deal with external files or you have to embed shaders into programs, which causes more work.

I have very little experience. I'd like to learn more about the subject, but because of this incomprehensible contradiction, I'm unable to progress.

So, *why use GLSL along with OpenGL*?

Comment: Well, OpenGL doesn't tell your graphics hardware *how* to draw something, just *what* to draw. The deprecated functions used to pre-package the "how" for you. Now you need to do it yourself. My understanding of OpenGL/GLSL isn't exactly top-notch and I don't have a complete answer, therefore this comment.

Comment: @Hydronium: OK, this helps a little, though. Thanks, I appreciate the gesture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not about GLSL; it's about *shaders* in general. GLSL is just the sanctioned way to provide shaders in OpenGL. Your question is really, "Why use shaders along with OpenGL?"

I'm not going to get into all of the details of what shaders can do that fixed function cannot. But here are just a few of the things that you cannot do with fixed-function OpenGL:

- GPU-powered [vertex weighted skinning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation).

  - Dual-quaternion-based skinning.
- Proper [tangent-space bump mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping).
- Various [deferred rendering techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_shading).
- On-GPU [frustum culling for instanced rendering](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/02/instance-culling-using-geometry-shaders/).
- Arbitrary lighting models, including [BRDFs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_reflectance_distribution_function) or other [complex illumination models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specular_highlight#Models_of_microfacets).
- [Complex shadow mapping techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_mapping#Shadow_mapping_techniques).
- [High-dynamic range rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_rendering) (OpenGL FFP doesn't let you exceed 1.0 on any color calculations).

  - Arbitrary [tone mapping techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_mapping).

I can keep going (for a *long* time), but I think you get the point. If you actually *care* about little things like "visual fidelity", you should be using shaders.

The question isn't "why use shaders;" it's "why *not* use shaders?"

Comment: I think he doesn't understand what the separation between OpenGL (the API) and shaders are, not so much shaders vs fixed function. Unless this answer covers the same ground? Informative nonetheless.